# Unexpected wakeup from suspend in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: suspend

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my laptop. A few minutes after putting the system to suspend, it wakes up automatically. tlp is installed on my system. I also have a usb keyboard and mouse connected to the laptop.

The contents of `/proc/acpi/wakeup` are:-

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled
KBD0      S3    *enabled   pnp:00:07
PS2M      S3    *disabled  pnp:00:08
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
PXSX      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:05:00.0
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEG3      S4    *disabled
LID0      S3    *enabled
```

output of `lspci`:-

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Any suggestions on how I can correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried unplugging the keyboard and mouse. It could be that subtle movements of the mouse might trigger wake-up.

On a side-note: can you post the results of `lspci` from the terminal. It might show what devices have the possibility of 'waking-up' the laptop when you connect the pci codes from both outputs.

**edit:** I see that most of the things that enable your computer to wake-up are usb connected. You could try to disable these, if you don't use usb connected software to wake from suspend anyway.

You can use the `sudo sh -c "echo **** > /proc/acpi/wakeup"` command to disable (or enable) things in the wakeup file. The `****` should be replaced with the device you wish to enable/disable (for instance EHC2 or KBD0) from the wakeup file.

Let me know if this works or not, so i can look for other solutions.

Comment: Moving the mouse or typing on the keyboard connected to usb is not causing the computer to wake up from suspend.